# Produce Messages in Kafka in HDF3.0.2 from local machine

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-dataflow

I have Hortonworks DataFlow (HDF3.0.2) running in VmWare on my mac. Kafka broker is running on port 6667 and the IP address of sandbox is 172.17.0.2

In java program, running locally on my mac, I have bootstrap server configured as below:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "172.17.0.2:6667");
```

Java program just hangs cannot produce message in kafka topic. I have tried disabling the firewall, added entry in /etc/hosts as:

```
172.17.0.2 sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com
```

and changed the bootstrap servers config entry to use sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com, but no luck.

telnet command to 172.17.0.2 6667 hangs as well and it gives connection timeout error.

Any help to produce message in Kafka running in HDF 3.0.2 from outside of Vmware is highly appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks for your time and help.